# How to set up Gunicorn and NGNIX for a Django project in a production environment?

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, wsgi

I'm trying to re-create a production environment on my local computer before deploying the Django project I have built on a server. I am using Gunicorn and NGNIX. When I launch Gunicorn by writing `gunicorn mydjangoproject.wsgi`, I get my Django project displayed on the address `http://127.0.0.1:8000`, but without any static files. That tells me that the error lies somewhere within NGINX, but I can't figure out where.

I have followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-debian-10) in order to set up Gunicorn and NGNIX on my local computer. I have skipped steps 5 to 7 in the guide because I do not want to deal with sockets on my local computer.

Here are the relevant parts of my `settings.py` file of my Django project:

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'production_static/')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```

Here's the file that's located at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/mydjangoproject`:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /production_static/ {
        root /home/john/Documents/Django_projects/mydjangoproject/Version_2/mydjangoproject;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

I have done all the other steps at step 8 of the guide I linked - I ran `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/mydjangoproject /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`, `sudo nginx -t` and `sudo systemctl restart nginx` after I made the NGINX config file above. I also ran `manage.py collectstatic` beforehand.

**Can you tell me what I did wrong? Are the config files valid given my project setup?**

Comment: The ideal here would be to setup the project with docker so that your local and remote are exactly* the same.

Comment: @markwalker_ OK, but can you tell me what is going wrong here (if you can see it from the config files I posted)? I could try to mess with the ports, but I'd like to avoid it because this is my local computer, not the server.

Comment: Hard to say. But really your `STATICFILES_DIRS` should use something like `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),`. And take the slash off the end of `STATIC_ROOT`. That looks odd/wrong.

Comment: @markwalker_ thank you. I dug into the issue some more and will open another question.